# awk: printing lines side by side when the first field is the same in the records

Tags: awk, append

I have a file containing lines like

```
a x1
b x1
q xq
c x1
b x2
c x2
n xn
c x3
```

I would like to test on the fist field in each line, and if there is a match I would like to append the matching lines to the first line. The output should look like

```
a x1
b x1 b x2
q xq
c x1 c x2 c x3
n xn
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk '{arr[$1]=arr[$1]?arr[$1] " " $0:$0} END {for (i in arr) print arr[i]}' file
n xn
a x1
b x1 b x2
c x1 c x2 c x3
q xq
```

Comment: That will produce a syntax error on some awks (OSX?) due to missing brackets around the ternary operator. `arr[$1]=arr[$1]?arr[$1] " " $0:$0` should be written `arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] " " $0:$0)` or even better to remove the redundancy of specifying $0 twice: `arr[$1] = (arr[$1]?arr[$1] " ":"") $0`

Answer (score 2):

To preserve input ordering:

```
$ awk '
{
    if ($1 in vals) {
        prev = vals[$1] " "
    }
    else {
        prev = ""
        keys[++k] = $1
    }
    vals[$1] = prev $0
}
END {
    for (k=1;k in keys;k++)
        print vals[keys[k]] 
}
' file
a x1
b x1 b x2
q xq
c x1 c x2 c x3
n xn
```

Comment: This was a long time back! Saw it today, thanks for your reply- and the well formatted code- hope others will find it helpful. For me, the project I was working on was time sensitive and I had to do a work around with my limited understanding. Here is what I ended up doing:-

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing. (The answers by Ed Morton and Jonte are obviously more elegant.)

First I saved the 1st column of the input file in a separate file.

```
awk '{print $1}' input.file.txt > tmp0
```

Then saved the input file with lines, which has duplicate values at $1 field, removed.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" }; !x[$1]++ { print $0}' input_file.txt > tmp1
```

Then saved all the lines with duplicate $1 field.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t" }; x[$1]++ { print $0}' input_file.txt >tmp2
```

Then saved the $1 fields of the non-duplicate file (tmp1).

```
awk '{ print $1}' tmp1 > tmp3
```

I used a for loop to pull in lines from the duplicate file (tmp2) and the duplicates removed file (tmp1) into an output file.

```
for i in $(cat tmp3)
do
if [ $(grep -w $i tmp0 | wc -l) = 1 ] #test for single instance in the 1st col of input file
then
echo "$(grep -w $i tmp1)" >> output.txt #if single then pull that record from no dupes
else
echo -e "$(grep -w $i tmp1) \t $(grep -w $i tmp2 | awk '{ 
            printf $0"\t" }; END { printf "\n" }')"   >> output.txt # if not single then pull that record from no_dupes first then all the records from dupes in a single line.
fi
done
```

Finally remove the tmp files

```
rm tmp* # remove all the tmp files
```